# How do we change the position of legend in chart.js-2 react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

i am trying to move the legends from top to bottom but not able to move the position
Since i am learning charts and trying to implement it to react need some help

also i need to change the size of the doughnut chart(should be small/thin) and need to add c text at center

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";
 import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

 ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

 export const data = {
 labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
 datasets: [
 {
  label: "# of Votes",
  data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
  backgroundColor: [
    "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
    "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
    "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
    "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
    "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
    "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
  ],
  borderColor: [
    "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
    "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
    "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
    "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
    "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
    "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
  ],
  borderWidth: 1,
  Legend: {
    display: true,
    position: "bottom",
  },
  },
  ],
  };

  export function App() {
  return <Doughnut data={data} />;
  }
```

I tried adding postions={legend:{position:"bottom"}}

also

```
const options = {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      padding: 20
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Chart.js version 4.n, [`legend`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) options need to be defined inside `options.plugins.legend`. The legend can be moved to the bottom of the chart through the [`position`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#position) option as follows:

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
you already have data object.
you need options object. 

for example in Doughnut chart : 
const options = { 
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      titleFont: {
        size: 20
      },
      bodyFont: {
        size: 20
      },
   },
  legend: {
    display: true,
    responsive: true,
    position: "bottom",
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 36,
      padding: 40,
      font: {
        size: 34
      },
    },
    align: "center",
  },
}

in this example you can also change box size, styles toolltip, set padding, font size ... 

<Doughnut data={data} options={options} />;
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the config that works for me (version 4.4).

```
<Doughnut
  options={{
    ...
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).